# Allocate memory for struct and call functions outside main()

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am cleaning up my `int main()`. Since I am a beginner in C, I used to write all my stuff inside the `main()`-function. Now I wanted to put some functions which I call in other functions into one single small function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <myStructs.h> // Here are my structs geo ,tree and par defined
#include <myFunct.h> // Here are my functions

// Structs
geo dom;
tree **root;
par *p;

void settree(tree **root, par *p, geo dom){
     root = malloc(sizeof(tree*));
     *root = calloc(1, sizeof(tree));
     compDom(&dom, p);
     initTree(root, &dom, p);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    int n = 100;
    p = malloc(sizeof(_Particle) * n); // Allocate memory for par
    anop = n;

    // Load particle data
    par *parptr = p;
    getData(parptr, n);

    double T = 20;
    double g = 1;
    for(double h=0; h<T; h+=g){           
        /// Build tree ///
        settree(*root, p, dom);
        /// Integration ///
        ec(root, p, n, g);
        /// Free Memory ///
        freeTree(*root);
        free(root);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have problems with the function `settree()`. I get a segmentation fault all the time. But why? Is something wrong with my pointers in this function? Can someone give me a hint how I work in this case with pointers? I am almost sure that there is somewhere my error.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared root as a global variable and passing it to the settree function like this:

```
settree(root, ...)
```

Your `settree` function looks like this (I have renamed the root parameter to myroot for distinguishing from the global variable)

```
 void settree(tree **myroot, par *p, geo dom){
 myroot = malloc(sizeof(tree*));
 *myroot = calloc(1, sizeof(tree));
 compDom(&dom, p);
 initTree(myroot, &dom, p);
```

}

Now, you are passing the global variable `root` to `settree()` as a parameter. Since it is a parameter to `settree()`, it is local to the function (allocated on the stack) and not really referring to the global variable `root`. When you call `malloc()` to allocate memory for `myroot` in `settree()`, it is the local variable `myroot` which is being assigned that address and the global variable `root` remains unchanged. Therefore, after calling `settree()`, when you try to use the global variable `root` inside `main`, you get a segfault, because it hasn't been initialized.

You can think of it this way. If you have a function like this:

```
void do_double(int x) {
    x = x * 2;
}
```

and call it from main like this:
    int i = 10;
    do_double(i);

The value of `i` remains the same, because when you called `do_double(i)`, a copy of `i` was created on the stack of `do_double()`, so any modifications inside `do_double()` will not affect `i`. Instead if `do_double` was like this:

```
void do_double(int *x) {
    *x = *x * 2;
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
i = 10;
do_double(&i);
```

Now, you are passing the address of `i`, and `do_double` is writing to that address, so `i` is getting updated. Similarly, when you are calling `settree(root)`, the `myroot` parameter is local to the function and any changes made there will not affect the global `root` variable. Instead, you need to do something like this:

(I would get rid of the global variable root and declare it inside main)

```
void settree(tree **root, par *p, geo dom){
     *root = calloc(1, sizeof(tree));
     compDom(&dom, p);
     initTree(root, &dom, p);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    int n = 100;
    p = malloc(sizeof(_Particle) * n); // Allocate memory for par
    anop = n;
    tree *root;


    // Load particle data
    par *parptr = p;
    getData(parptr, n);

    double T = 20;
    double g = 1;
    for(double h=0; h<T; h+=g){           
        /// Build tree ///
        settree(&root, p, dom);
       /// Integration ///
       ec(root, p, n, g);
      /// Free Memory ///
      freeTree(root);
   }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: That does not solve my problem. I  still get seg. faults. The error is probably somewhere else. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace from the segfault?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Sorry. As I said, I am a beginner in C and the console shows me only `Segmentation fault`. If I put the content of `settree()` inside the `main()` than the program works.

Comment: Assuming you are using Linux, compile your program with -g option of gcc. Something like gcc -g -o main myprogram.c. After that, run it with gdb, like this: gdb ./main. Now run the program by entering r. Your program will halt after the segfault, then type bt in the gdb prompt and see the stacktrace to see exactly which line is causing the segfault.

Comment: I did what you said and get the following output in case that I only want to allocate memory in the function `settree()`: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000405c59 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde88) at nbody.c:46
46         *root = calloc(1, sizeof(treenode));
(gdb)`. So the function I called outside the `main()` was `void settree(tree **root, par *p, geo dom){
    root = malloc(sizeof(treenode*));
}`

Comment: Alright, I understood the problem, I will post a new answer and delete this one.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I need the global variable. I would your example look like if there was a global variable `tree **rood`?

Comment: That will work too. I removed the global variable because it's not a good practice to use them